# Does Next.js 11.0.0 support barrel(index) files?

Tags: next.js, es6-modules

Barrel/index files seem to create issues when used with next.js. It doesn't seem established if it's purely a webpack issue or both webpack and next.js

According to [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12557) tree shaking stops working if we use barrel files. I also created [a small repo](https://github.com/zen-testt/next-index-re-export) where I have an issue with an index file. Not sure if it's a tree shaking issue.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- `npm install`
- `npm run dev`
- in browser, visit http://localhost:3000/about-pro, expect to see blank page with errors or warnings in browser's console
- go to server's console(where you run `npm run dev`)
- see an error of sort "*Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'*" (1) (2) (3)

1- this comes from the `await serialize` in `getAboutPageData` file. Which itself is only called within `getStaticProps`

2 - googling for this issue, you'll find solutions such as modifying `next.config.js` file. It still doesn't work. Feel free to uncomment the `next.config.js` file and see for yourself

3 - to "solve" the issue, go to `about-pro.tsx`, in the imports, import `AboutPage` from its own file instead of from the barrel/index file

If I only import `getAboutPageData` from the barrel/index file, then it works fine. But as soon as I import e.g. `AboutPage` from it, it starts throwing unrelated issues.

Can I continue using barrel/index files with next.js and if yes, is there a simple and intuitive way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not in the **barrel** files themselves but in the **library** that you're using combined with **barrel** files.

If you take a look at the **readme** file https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-remote#examples you can find a warning:

> IMPORTANT: Be very careful about putting any `mdx-remote` code into a separate "utilities" file. Doing so will likely cause issues with nextjs' code splitting abilities - it must be able to cleanly determine what is used only on the server side and what should be left in the client bundle. If you put `mdx-remote` code into an external utilities file and something is broken, remove it and start from the simple example above before filing an issue.

So in order to make your code work you need to remove the export of `getAboutPageData` from your barrel file, like this:

```js
export { default as AboutPage } from './AboutPage';
// export { default as getAboutPageData } from './getAboutPageData';
```

and move the code that uses the library inside the `about-pro.tsx` file.

```js
import { AboutPage } from '../modules/about';
import { serialize } from 'next-mdx-remote/serialize';

const AboutPro = (props) => {
  return <AboutPage {...props} />;
};

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const serializedContent = await serialize(`# Header1`);
  const data = serializedContent;
  return { props: {} };
};

export default AboutPro;
```

I think the issue is that the modules imported in barrel files are executed both **client** and **server** side. Probably removing side effects from the **barrel** file could solve the issue, but I don't know enough about **Next.js** to be able to do it correctly.